# Estimating time when IDs reach a particular value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a database with tables like this:

```
+------+-------------+-----------------------+
| ID   | DATE        | Data                  |
+------+-------------+-----------------------+
| 1    | dd.mm.yyyy  | ...                   |
| 2    | dd.mm.yyyy  | ...                   |
| 5    | dd.mm.yyyy  | ...                   |
| 6    | dd.mm.yyyy  | ...                   |
+------+-------------+-----------------------+
```

Here ID comes from [sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql) that is splitted between different tables. I'm working with a particular table with the set of IDs (100 millions) in it which continually being added here. I want to estimate when an ID will reach particular value (say, 1 billion).

**Can you help me to write a query that would solve this (important requirement: as few CASE statements as possible) ?**

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Are you inserting rows here on a regular basis (like 1 row per second) or what? Because it sounds to me as though you want a SQL statement that can predict the future. Pretty sure anyone that could write that wouldn't give it to you for free. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could assume a linear growth and extrapolate in time.

```
        .---- E = Expected ID
       /|
      / |
     /  |
    .---|---- L = Last Id = MAX(ID)
   /|   |
  / |   |
 /  |   |
+---+---+---- F = First ID = MIN(ID)
D1  D2  Dx
```

D1 = first Date = MIN(DATE)
D2 = last date = MAX(DATE)
Dx = Estimated date (result)

Using the proportions in the triangle we get:

```
D2 - D1   Dx - D1
------- = -------
 L - F     E - F
```

After transformation of the formula

```
               D2 - D1
Dx = (E - F) * ------- + D1
                L - F
```

Change the order of the operations and divide by `L - F` before multiplying to avoid overflow. Make date first operand to get date type as result.

```
Dx = D1 + (E - F) / (L - F) * (D2 - D1)
```

As SQL

```
SELECT
    MIN("DATE") + (1000000000 - MIN(ID)) / (MAX(ID) - MIN(ID)) * 
    (MAX("DATE") - MIN("DATE")) AS DateReachedGivenId
FROM YourTable
```

Note that if the result year is greater than 9999, Oracle will generate an error. If this occures, you could simply calculate the number of days left until you reach the max Id with

```
SELECT (1000000000 - MIN(ID)) / (MAX(ID) - MIN(ID)) * (MAX("DATE") - MIN("DATE")) AS DaysLeft
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: This assumes a linear distribution.

Comment: Yes, it does. You have to make an assumption. If the speed of insertion varies over the years, you could also use only the data of the last year, for instance. But then you have to take the MIN(ID) of this period into account in the formula.

Comment: Of course you "have to make an assumption" (well, it would be best if the OP, or his business customer, made the assumption, not someone trying to help the OP on Stack Overflow). But why would you make the assumption of LINEARITY, of all the possible choices? Why not exponential growth, for example - which is much more common?

Comment: You would have to use a regression model whose formula is quite complicated for SQL. But of course it would be possible. Why don't you post an answer for an exponential model?